# Can't connect to Default Web Site in IIS 6.0

Tags: iis

I can't connect to the default web site in IIS 6.0 using localhost or 127.0.0.1 or by server name. When I telnet to port 80 with one of these names, there's no connection.

However other web sites are running and I can telnet using any of the ip addresses.
I can ping to localhost where 127.0.0.1 is responding.
The default web site is running. It's not stopped.

Comment: Can you connect with your actual IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

httpcfg.exe did it.

Answer (score 1):

check the windows firewall, that has a habit of blocking IIS on a local machine

Comment: Windows firewall is not running. I use another firewall software and even when it allows everything, I am still getting the same issue.

Does Windows firewall block 127.0.0.1 specifically? Cause when using other local ip addresses, it works.

Comment: if you right click browse on one of the files in the IIS manager does that work?

Comment: No. I get the same error. 
When I run 'netstat -an -p tcp', I am not getting 0.0.0.0:80 which is expected.

Answer (score 1):

Is the default site bound to a specific IP address?  By default it would display "all unassigned" for the IP, but if you've linked all sites to a specific IP address, then the local IP would no longer be configured on the server and would not answer.

Answer (score 0):

Stop all the sites under IIS, restart IIS and start the one you're interested in.

If this fails delete all the sites under IIS and create from scratch. If *this* fails, the problem is not with IIS and you'll need to look at what other services are running and start turning them off.

Comment: Your first suggestion didn't help. This is a production server so I can't delete sites.

I don't understand your suggestion about other services. Why would 127.0.0.1 not work but an actual ip work for the port 80? I assuming your suggestion is about another service taking over port 80?

Comment: not really about the ports no, more about the specific localhost nature if you can't reach servername, localhost or 127.0.0.1 - I feel it's likely that some other service (by which I mean firewalls mostly, but could be anything) is obstructing or overprotecting so in a vacuum I'd want to simplify.

Answer (score 0):

A firewall may prevent some content of your website/website itself from being accessible, so if you have problems with accessing content then check that your firewall is not rejecting content from your site.

The easiest way to ensure that your firewall is not blocking your access to your site services is to use your firewall control panel to allow data from `*.(your site url)`.

Comment: It's not the firewall. The firewall has an "Allow All" option which didn't help.