# ASP.NET site deployment on local network

Tags: asp.net, iis

I've created an ASP.NET application and want to deploy it on an XP Pro. machine so it will be available from other computers in the same local network.

**What is the right configuration to achieve that?**

I've tried to create the application on IIS 7 in Win 7 machine (at home, before going to the customer), but wasn't able to load it from other machine on the network.

Same problem when deploying the site on XP Pro. machine in a virtual machine and trying lo load it from the host machine.

I've canceled an ASP.NET problem by putting  a simple html file in the application directory and trying to reach it.

**Can you direct me to some check list about deploying a website?**

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I've searched before asking, I've searched again now.
Found this:  [Can't connect to Default Web Site in IIS 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/355358/cant-connect-to-default-web-site-in-iis-6-0)

Disable windows firewall and everything is working....

I fill stupid...

Answer (score 0):

Follow this guide: http://www.wikihow.com/Configure-IIS-for-Windows-XP-Pro

Answer (score 0):

Should this post be moved to [serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/)?  It seems to be a configuration/deployment issue not a programming problem.

Comment: As far as I know you would have to close this post and open it on serverfault.com.  Truthfully I am new to this site so I am not sure of the etiquette on this site.